# Finding $x^3+y^3$, given $x + y = 5$ and $xy = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given
> $$x + y = 5 \qquad xy = 1$$
> Find $x^3 + y^3$.

To solve this, I tried this:

$y = \frac{1} {x}$

$x + \frac{1}{x} = 5$

$x^2 - 5x + 1 = 0$

What formula needs to be used to find the value of $x$?

Comment: Here's a question. What happens when you expand out $(x-2.5)^2$? (This is not necessary for solving the problem.)

Answer (score 5):

Another method that requires some intuition and knowledge of cubics:

Observe that, $$\large{\displaystyle{(\color{red}{x + y})^3 = \color{purple}{x}^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + \color{purple}{y}^3} = \color{purple}{x}^3 + 3\color{green}{xy}\big(\color{red}{x+y}\big) + \color{purple}{y}^3}$$

Otherwise re-arranged, gives:

$$\large{\displaystyle{\color{purple}{x}^3 + \color{purple}{y}^3 =(\color{red}{x + y})^3 - 3\color{green}{xy}\big(\color{red}{x+y}\big)}}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{aligned}
x^3+y^3 & =(x+y)^3-3 x y(x+y) \\
& =5^3-3(1)(5) \\
& =110
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: On the money, neat.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the quadratic formula, or use a trick. Recall that $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2) $.
Now consider that $x^2-xy+y^2=(x+y)^2-3xy$

So you have:
$$x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=(x+y)((x+y)^2-3xy)  $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^3)$. We have $x+y=5$. Then $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy=25$. Then, $x^2-xy+y^2=25-3xy=22$. All that is left is to multiply them.

Answer (score 1):

Use the binomial formula. We have
$$(x+y)^3=x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3,$$
which reduces to
$$125=x^3 + 3\cdot 5 + y^3$$
and thus
$$x^3 + y^3 = 110.$$

There is no need to solve for $x$.